# Why is the Matomo tracking code the way it is

Tags: javascript, matomo

The default code to include Matomo analysis in a website looks like this:

```html
<!-- Matomo -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//{$MATOMO_URL}/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', {$IDSITE}]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- End Matomo Code -->
```

I wonder why this is so complicated:

- `matomo.js` expects a global variable `window._paq`. Why not directly initialize it:

  `window._paq = [['trackPageView'], ['enableLinkTracking'], ...];`
- What is the immediately invoked function expression doing? Just to hide 'u', 'd' and so on from the global scope?
- A script is inserted by DOM manipulation. Wouldn't it be simpler to just place a `<script src="matomo.js"></script>` tag after this block?

*Edit with the information I was looking for, because I can't answer myself anymore:*

As René Roth [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602091/143091), the code does nothing except the obvious - it sets or extends `_paq`, and includes the other script. It is fully equivalent to this, which doesn't look obfuscated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._paq = [
    ['trackPageView'],
    ['enableLinkTracking'],
    ['setTrackerUrl', '//matomo.example.com/matomo.php'],
    ['setSiteId', '2'],
]
</script>
<script src="//matomo.example.com/matomo.js" type="text/javascript" async="true"></script>
```

Comment: Hiding variables from outer scripts is definitely a goal for tracker script since some AddBlocker like UBlock look for these signs (among others)

Comment: @MoPaMo yes, but the default code is *very* conspicuous and uBlock Origin blocks it by default anyway. I don't believe this is an attempt to get around adblockers.

Comment: 1) consider what happens if the snippet is included multiple times with different `$IDSITE` 2) yes 3) so that the script loads asynchronously (even in old browsers not supporting the `async` attribute)

Comment: I would like to answer my own question with new information. Can somebody please reopen it?

Answer (score 2):

> matomo.js expects a global variable window._paq. Why not directly
> initialize it:
>
> window._paq = [['trackPageView'], ['enableLinkTracking'], ...];

There might be instances where the `_paq` variable is already defined and includes some additional options you might want or need. In this case, this way of initializing prevents overriding the pre-defined options.

> What is the immediately invoked function expression doing? Just to
> hide 'u', 'd' and so on from the global scope?

It is best practice to not pollute the global namespace with variables, you might already have a variable named `u` or `d` in the global scope.

> A script is inserted by DOM manipulation. Wouldn't it be simpler to
> just place a  tag after this block?

You could do this, but then you'd need to make sure `_paq` is defined before the script gets called. This way, all relevant information is in one place and the options are definitely set before the main matomo script is run.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I thought. So there is no neccessity *per se* that the code is this way. Especially since it is presented as "copy this code into your vanilla page" - people copying the snippet are not likely to already have code for matomo in there.